# Merging multiple pandas dataframes by common STRINGS in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have 6 csv files in which one column is a sentence and the second column is an integer.

The sentences are the same across all csv files, but they are out of key order from file to file.

I want to merge all data frames by sentence, so that I have one column of the sentences and then each integer column associated with that sentence from each csv file.

I've tried various merging and reducing techniques by the common 'sentence' column, but I end up with orders of magnitude more rows than I should have.

For example:

```
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y, on='sentence', how='inner'), data_frames)
```

results in a dataframe with 12,502,455 rows!! I only have 4,825 rows in each csv file.

even using:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, on='sentence', how='inner')
```

results in a dataframe with 5295 rows.

I know all the sentences are identical across csv files because I uploaded the same csv file of sentences to mTurk to be labeled.

Comment: Are you sure all of the sentences are unique?  `df['sentence'].nunique().eq(len(df))` If you are sure each dataframe contains the same sentences, perhaps you can sort them on this column. To find the dups: `df[df['sentence'].duplicated()]`

Comment: thanks. looks like there were in fact duplicates in the original csv file I was unaware of. Turkers labeled them differently... Closing the issue

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your code is running correctly. I'm guessing the problem is that your sentences are not distinct. if you have duplicate sentences, running an inner join will multiply them. google "cartesian product"
can you post how many duplicate sentences are in each file?

Answer (score 0):

You might have strings with different values.
Ensure to preprocess them before by doing lower and strip.
Example:

```
new_dfs = []
for df in dfs:
   df['sentence'] = df['sentence'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().strip())
   new_dfs.append(df)
```

Then, you can do simply merge as you mentioned. Make sure to have similar named columns.

Here's a simple working example:

```
import pandas as pd

vals1 =  [[1, 'doc'], [2, 'bac'], [3, 'mec']]
vals2 =  [[22, 'doc'], [12, 'mec'], [67, 'bac']]
vals3 =  [[15, 'mec'], [35, 'bac'], [122, 'doc']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=vals1, columns=["x","y"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=vals2, columns=["x","y"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=vals3, columns=["x","y"])
df4 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='y', how='inner', suffixes=("1","2"))
df4 = pd.merge(df4, df3, on='y', how='inner')
df4.head()
```

Result:

[image]